# Change salloc behavior to run all commands on remote node

Tags: slurm

The default behaviour for `salloc` will run any shell related commands on the node where `salloc` was called from, while any `srun` commands called from that `salloc` job shell will run on the node that was allocated. Does anyone know of a way to get `salloc` to interactively run all commands on the remote node job shell?

Below is an example of the current default behaviour I'm seeing. Ideally, the first hostname command would run on slurm-node02 and return that hostname. Thanks!

```
[testyboi@slurm-node01 ~]$ salloc --nodelist=slurm-node02
salloc: Granted job allocation 890
[testyboi@slurm-node01 ~]$ hostname
slurm-node01
[testyboi@slurm-node01 ~]$ cat salloctest.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "I am running on "; hostname;
[testyboi@slurm-node01 ~]$ srun -N1 salloctest.sh
I am running on
slurm-node02
```

Answer (score 2):

The former FAQ, relevant for versions prior to 20.11, suggested to set

```
SallocDefaultCommand="srun -n1 -N1 --mem-per-cpu=0 --pty --preserve-env --cpu-bind=no --mpi=none $SHELL"
```

in `slurm.conf`. For the current version, 20.11, there is a new option. You can set

```
LaunchParameters=use_interactive_step
```

in `slurm.conf`.

Comment: This fixed my issue, buy my reputation score is too low to mark this suggestion as an answer. Did you just use internet wayback machine to find the older FAQ or is it posted somewhere else on their site?

Comment: The documentation is on their GitHub account so it is jus a matter of choose the correct git release tag to got back in time.